# Making off-canvas navigation scrollable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navigation

I have this off-canvas navigation: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/IcBis.
How do I make it scrollable like this one: http://codepen.io/jdigi/pen/nafJc ?

I only know how to make mine scrollable with scrollbar, but it still acts as a seperate element, rather than merged with rest of the body. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the menus positioning from fixed to absolute. And to achieve full height, set the body's positioning to relative.

[Updated code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/tsGpc)

Answer (score 0):

You've (accidentally?) applied the `fixed` CSS rule to the `#menu` element.

The [`fixed` CSS rule](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-position/#fixed-positioning) "nails" a block element to the viewport and keeps it from being scrollable.

This is ideal for watermarks but, I guess, not what you've intended.

Replace

```
#menu {
     position: fixed;
```

with

```
#menu {
     position: absolute;
```

That'll fix your problem.